# ls command operating differently depending on recipient

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, ls, tty

How does commands like `ls` know what its stdout is?

It seems `ls` is operating different depending on what the target stdout is. For example if I do:

```
ls /home/matt/tmp
```

the result is:

```
a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

However if I do

```
ls /home/matt/tmp | cat
```

the result is (i.e. new line per result):

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

The process is passed a file descriptor 1 for stdout right? How does it determine how to format the result? Does the file descriptor reveal information?

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157285/4671, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63108/4671 and probably others. It seems to be a popular topic. This might be a dupe of one of these.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `ls` program uses `isatty()` to know whether fd 1 is a tty or something else (pipe, file, etc…). From `man 3 isatty`:

> ```
> int isatty(int fd);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>         The `isatty()` function tests whether `fd` is an open file descriptor
>         referring to a terminal

---

**Updade:** Line 1538 in `ls.c` from coreutils (git revision 43a987e1):

```
  if (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO))
    {
      format = many_per_line;
      /* See description of qmark_funny_chars, above.  */
      qmark_funny_chars = true;
    }
```

(`many_per_line` should be self-descriptive.)

Answer (score 8):

Not an exact answer but an exemplification. In a Bash script you can achieve similar effect with `test`/`[[`'s `-t`:

> `-t FD          True if FD is opened on a terminal.`

Using it like this:

```
bash-4.2$ where() { [[ -t 1 ]] && echo 'my output goes to TTY' || echo 'my output is redirected'; }

bash-4.2$ where
my output goes to TTY

bash-4.2$ where | cat
my output is redirected

bash-4.2$ where > test.file
bash-4.2$ cat test.file
my output is redirected
```

Answer (score 6):

From the OpenBSD `ls(1)` [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ls):

> By default, ls lists one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when the -C, -m, or -x options are specified.

Then, later:

> -1 (The numeric digit ``one''.) Force output to be one entry per line.  This is the default when output is not to a terminal.

[...]

> -C Force multi-column output; this is the default when output is to a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You may execute `ls` in a pseudo-terminal using the `script`  command, pipe the output of `ls` to another command and get the same output format as if there was no such piping of the stdout stream, i.e. as if stdout were a terminal (tty).

For the underlying `isatty()` mechanism already pointed out by Stéphane Gimenez see [ls.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-202.2/ls/ls.c).

```
ls -G /
ls -G / | cat
script -q /dev/null ls -G / | sed $'s/\r$//g' | cat

# tty | cat
# script -q /dev/null tty | cat
```