# Are unix[-like] programs capable of determing where their output is going?

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, colors, stdout, stdin

Up until recently I was under the impression that Unix-y programs were unaware of where their output went, be it to standard out, redirected to a file, or into a pipe. However, an unrelated U&L question on this site brought to my attention the following example:

```
% echo "hello world" > file

% grep --color=auto lo file
hello world

% grep --color=auto lo file | cat
hello world
```

Obviously you can't see it here, but the first command shows 'lo' highlighted, as expected. However, the second call, which goes through a pipe, shows no colour. This suggests that `grep` was aware of its output being directed to a pipe and avoided outputting colour. How is this done?

Comment: See [ls command operating differently depending on recipient](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22162/ls-command-operating-differently-depending-on-recipient) for a similar discussion.

Comment: The key is that classic command-line oriented unix programs *can* operate without knowing or caring what their stdin and stdout filehandles refer to, not that they must remain unaware. Besides color, tools like `ls` and `grep` will also treat whitespace differently if they think they're talking to a 2-dimensional console rather than a 1-dimensional file stream.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to determine whether a file descriptor refers to a tty.

Check out [the `isatty` function](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isatty&sektion=3).

Alternatively, you can use [the `fstat` function](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstat&sektion=2) which gives you a chunk of information on the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are. There are several methods to determine where the output is going. For a [comparison see my answer to a related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt/7601564#7601564).

Comment: Great, in-depth answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easily. Different ways can be used to determine where the output is going.
So in python you could do something like

```
    /* CODE. Input will be parsed and executed */
int
PyRun_AnyFileExFlags(FILE *fp, const char *filename, int closeit,
                     PyCompilerFlags *flags)
       {
    if (filename == NULL)
        filename = "???";
    if (Py_FdIsInteractive(fp, filename)) {
        int err = PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags(fp, filename, flags);
```