# Number of lines outputted by ls

Tags: ls, wc

When `ls` is called, it outputs all the files/directories in the current directory, attempting to fit as many as possible on each line. Why is it that when passed to `wc -l`, it outputs the number of files? How does it decide how many lines to output its results in?

Comment: Try `ls | cat` to see that `ls`'s output is different when it detects that its output is redirected.

Comment: The `COLUMNS` environment variable generally afftects the width of screen-formatted output.

Comment: Several commands will react differently if called from an interactive terminal. Depends on the command, GNU `ls` is one clear example, as you've found out. `wget` will use a dotted progress display, instead of the "animated" progress bar you get in "interactive mode".

Comment: @manatwork, not "output redirected" but "output isn't a tty".

Comment: @njsg, this isn't "GNU ls", it is POSIX-mandated behaviour. Right on the money on wget, thhough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `ls` is executed it parses various options. It also detect if output is a tty or not by [isatty()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/isatty.3.html).

`ls.c:`

*[code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n1536)*

```
case LS_LS:
  /* This is for the `ls' program.  */
  if (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO))
    {
      format = many_per_line;
      /* See description of qmark_funny_chars, above.  */
      qmark_funny_chars = true;
    }
  else
    {
      format = one_per_line;
      qmark_funny_chars = false;
    }
  break;
```

...

*[code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n1668)*

```
      /* disable -l */
      if (format == long_format)
        format = (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO) ? many_per_line : one_per_line);
```

etc.

---

If you want you can compile a simple test:

`isawhat.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Word by word my world.\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "HELP! Stranger handling my words!!\n");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Bye bye.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compile by:

```
gcc -o isawhat isawhat.c
```

Then e.g.:

```
$ ./isawhat | sed 's/word/world/'
```

---

Width is measured in columns. One column is one character. [It starts out with 80](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n1585), then check if the environment variable COLUMNS is set and holds a valid int that is not larger then SIZE_MAX (Which is arch dependant - your terminal will never be that wide (at least not yet)).

Try e.g. `echo $COLUMNS`. It most probably reflect the number of columns you have available in the window. As window get resized - this get updated. It most probably also get reset by various commands.

One way to set it a bit harder is by `stty`. E.g. `stty columns 60`. Use `stty -a` to view all (man stty). A fun piece of software.

If compiled in it also query for columns by [ioctl()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html), [Window size detect.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n1605). By passing the filenumber for stdout to `ioctl` and passing the request [TIOCGWINSZ](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl_list.2.html) the structure `winsize` get filled with the number of columns.

This can also be demonstrated by a simple c-code:

*Compile, run and resize window. Should update. Ctrl+C  to quit.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

static int run;

void sig_handler(int sig) {
    switch (sig) {
    case SIGINT:
    case SIGTERM:
    case SIGSTOP:
        run = 0;
        break;
    }
}

void sig_trap(int sig) {
    if ((signal(sig, sig_handler)) == SIG_IGN)
        signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct winsize ws;

    sig_trap(SIGINT);
    sig_trap(SIGTERM);
    sig_trap(SIGSTOP);

    run = 1;
    while (run) {
        if (ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) != -1) {
            fprintf(stdout, "\r %s: %3d, %s: %d\r",
                "Columns", ws.ws_col,
                "Rows", ws.ws_row
            );
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        usleep(5000);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When output is directed into a file descriptor other than a terminal (thus pipe, or file, or the like), `ls` behaves as if it was invoked as `ls -1`.

Comment: Output always go to stdout. What counts is whether stdout is a terminal or not. That is whether a user reads its output or not.