# Pass colors from ls through pipe to awk 'print' statement

Tags: bash, awk, ls, pipe, colors

This is a follow-up to my question from yesterday, [Show sum of file sizes in directory listing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72661/show-sum-of-file-sizes-in-directory-listing).

Thanks to [Zero Piraeus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27282/zero-piraeus) and a point in the right direction by [Mauritz Hansen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23445/mauritz-hansen), I now have

```
function dir() {
        ls -FaGl "${@}" | awk '{print; total += $4}; END {print "\t\ttotal: ",total/1024,"KB"}'
}
```

in my `.bash_profile`, and it works great. However, at least on Linux (I haven't had a chance to try it on OSX yet), where I'm `ssh`ing in using PuTTY on XP, my dir colors are now gone. Is there some way of passing the color codes through the pipe to the awk `print` statement?

#### Update

Thanks to Sukminder's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72804/19512), adding `--color=always` does the trick, as it had been set to `auto` before. However, I now get a blank space between the end of the directory listing and the total line:

```
[19:30:58 mattdmo@server ~/webapps/django15 ] $ dir
drwxr-xr-x  7 mattdmo 4096 Mar 24 20:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17 root    4096 Mar 18 20:15 ../
drwxr-xr-x  7 mattdmo 4096 Mar 14 14:57 apache2/
drwxr-xr-x  3 mattdmo 4096 Mar 14 14:57 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  2 mattdmo 4096 Mar 24 20:10 lib/
drwxr-xr-x  3 mattdmo 4096 Mar 14 14:57 myproject/
drwxrwxr-x  3 mattdmo 4096 Mar 24 20:28 pigimal/

                total:  28 KB
[19:30:59 mattdmo@server ~/webapps/django15 ] $
```

Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: Do not get that extra line here. What `ls` are you using? `ls --version` or the like. Why do you not have e.g. `total ...` at first line? Sure that's the whole script?

Comment: @Sukminder I'm using ls (GNU coreutils) 8.4 on linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 (my web hosting provider). Like I said below, I haven't tested this on my OSX box at home yet - that's running 10.8.3, and I'm fairly certain I have the GNU coreutils installed, but I'm out of town and won't know until tomorrow night. And yes, the full function body is `ls -FaGl "${@}" --color=always | awk '{print; total += $4}; END {print "\t\ttotal: ",total/1024,"KB"}'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using `ls --color=always` the colors should be preserved. I'm unsure if it 
is gnu specific though. [*Edit from OP: yes, it is.*]

The case is that `ls` detect whether output is to tty or not.

If it is not it normally do not print colors and do not translate
*"unprintable characters"* to question marks. This can be added by the `-q`
 [option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/ls.html).

More on the subject: [Number of lines outputted by ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63110/28489).

---

gnu coreutils source ls; ref. on some of the colors data:

- [enum definition.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n535)
- [link to option word](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n881)
- [option definition](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=a04ddb8dd3fffd3457f927a36f6840fc1465aba2#n840)

---

***Edit:***

For gnu coreutils ls: `--color=always`
For OS X's ls: set environment variable `CLICOLOR_FORCE` and `G` means color. The
core is conforming to [ls IEEE Std 1003.1-2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html). Other options are
extensions that wary between implementations.

OK. Had a deeper look at this. Though from what I read around people also 
install gnu coreutils on OS X, I guess you perhaps use the *original*.

The [OS X man pages for ls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) state:

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE  
    Color sequences are normally disabled if the output isn't directed to a
    terminal.  This can be overridden by setting this flag.  The TERM 
    variable still needs to reference a color capable terminal however
    otherwise it is not possible to determine which color sequences to use.
```

From the source:

[Mac OS X 10.8.2 Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1082/) -> [file_cmds-220.7](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-220.7/) -> [ls/](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-220.7/ls/)

From that code it is also quickly clear that one can set

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE
```

to force color.

As it first parses arguments and `setenv` color on `G`:

```
    case 'G':
        setenv("CLICOLOR", "", 1);
        break;
```

And after `argv` parsing:

```
/* CLICOLOR is set    AND    is a tty            OR */
if (getenv("CLICOLOR") && (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) || 
etenv("CLICOLOR_FORCE")))
/*  force cli color is set */
```

By next section if TERM is set, color is used:

```
if (tgetent(termcapbuf, getenv("TERM")) == 1) {
```

`echo $TERM` should yield a color capable terminal. But if you get
colors by normal this should be the case.

### ---

**Edit to last update:**

Not sure then. It is strange. Not only the extra line but also that you do
not have any `total ...` at the start. You could start out by checking the
output of something like this:

```
function dir() {
/bin/ls -FaGl "${@}" | awk '
    function chr2hex(chr) {
        return sprintf("%02x", index(i2x, chr));
    }
    function str2hex(str) {
        r = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= length(str); ++i)
            r = r chr2hex(substr(str, i, 1));
        return r;
    }
    BEGIN {
        i2x = ""
        for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            i2x = sprintf("%s%c", i2x, i);
        printf("FNR        : %d\n", FNR);
        printf("FIELDWIDTHS: \"%s\"\n", FIELDWIDTHS);
        printf("FS         : \"%s\"\n", str2hex(FS));
        printf("RS         : \"%s\"\n", str2hex(RS));
        printf("OFS        : \"%s\"\n", str2hex(OFS));
        printf("ORS        : \"%s\"\n", str2hex(OFS));
    }
    {
        printf("%2d:%2d:%2d \"%s\"\n", FNR, NR, NF, $0);
        total += $4;
    }
    END {
        printf("%21s: %d %s\n", "total", total / 1024, "KiB");
        printf("FNR        : %d\n", FNR);
        printf("From       : \"%s\"\n", FILENAME);
    }
'
}
```

Should give you something like – (*From* could be `"-"` by e.g. gawk):

```
$ ./dir testdir
FNR        : 0
FIELDWIDTHS: ""
FS         : "20"
RS         : "0a"
OFS        : "20"
ORS        : "20"
 1: 1: 2 "total 24"
 2: 2: 8 "drwxrwxr-x 6 mattdmo 4096 Apr 17 21:46 ./"
 3: 3: 8 "drwxrwxr-x 8 mattdmo 4096 Apr 18 10:47 ../"
 4: 4: 8 "drwxrwxr-x 2 mattdmo 4096 Apr 17 21:46 ab1/"
 5: 5: 8 "drwxrwxr-x 2 mattdmo 4096 Apr 17 21:46 ab2/"
 6: 6: 8 "drwxrwxr-x 2 mattdmo 4096 Apr 17 21:46 ab3/"
 7: 7: 8 "drwxrwxr-x 2 mattdmo 4096 Apr 17 21:46 ab4/"
                total: 24 KB
FNR        : 7
From       : ""
```

Comment: thanks, this works! However, please see my update above - there's now a blank line after the directory listing. Any ideas?

Comment: Tested it and do not get that trailing blank line. Does `ls -FaGlq` give you any question marks? Also; note as per the man pages for `ls` in OS X they only uses one letter options. G means color and one has to use `CLICOLOR_FORCE` environment variable to get color trough pipe. – as in no --color=always, and `G` does not mean `--no-group`. The version conforms to [ls IEEE Std 1003.1-2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html). And `G` etc. is extensions.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear - I tested it on Linux. I haven't had a chance to test OSX at home yet, but I'm glad to hear it works as expected.

Comment: My test was on debian using ls (GNU coreutils) 8.13.