# Why don't I see escape sequences in redirected stream OR how is color output implemented?

Tags: terminal, ls, colors, escape-characters

When running `ls` in terminal, output is variously colored:

[image: ls console output]

AFAIK this colorasing is accomplished by espace sequences (vt).

But running `ls | hexdump -cC` shows only characters and LFs. Redirection to file leads to similar results.

[image: ls | hexdump -cC console output]

How is that?

Comment: Use `ls --color=always | hexdump -cC`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72799/pass-colors-from-ls-through-pipe-to-awk-print-statement and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185544/no-colored-output-in-less-for-the-ls-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU `ls` only outputs escape sequences for colorized text when writing to a terminal, not when redirected to a file or pipe.

For that, use `ls --color=always`.

The GNU `ls` manual says:

```
   Using color to distinguish file types is disabled both by default and
   with --color=never.  With --color=auto, ls emits color codes only when
   standard output is connected to a terminal.  [...]
```

I'm guessing that your `ls` command behaves like `ls --color=auto` by default, possibly through the use of an `ls` alias.

Comment: Ok, the question should be more like "how do commands know whether stdout is terminal", but since it does not, this is the answer.

Comment: @mcpiroman This is easy to test.  In the shell, one could use `if [ -t 1 ]; then ...; fi` to test whether file descriptor 1 (standard output) is a terminal.

Comment: Well that's interesting cause I thought the streams and pipes where designed to be transparent i.e. that the actual output file (linux file) is not known nor relevant. I'm guessing that's a little bit of a hack to that system, but that's ok.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/932170.

Comment: @mcpiroman It is transparent, in the sense that writing to a pipe and writing to a file is done in exactly the same way. Likewise is reading done the same way. 
 A pipe may however not be searched (you can't set the file pointer to a specific location in a data stream coming off a pipe). There are also ways to inspect the nature of file descriptors. A program may then decide to act on the result of such inspection, obviously.