# How can I keep color codes with grep input?

Tags: shell, grep, colors

If I use two consecutive `grep` commands, e.g.:

```
echo "foo bar" | grep foo | grep bar
```

Then the first pattern ("foo") is not highlighted.
In fact, it seems that grep removes color codes from its input. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Another question with the same answer:  how can you restore colored output to a grep within a bash function?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `--color=always`.

`grep` detects if output is to a pipe (or file). You most never want colors when output is to file – as that is escape sequences for the terminal. Typically:

```
foo ^[[01;31m^[[Kbar^[[m^[[K
```

from e.g.:

```
grep pattern file > result
```

To override use `--color=always`.

```
grep --color=always pattern file | ...
```

---

Example:

Having file:

```
ID=111;Year=2013;foo=bar
ID=222;Year=2013;foo=baz
```

Then

```
grep --color=always ID file | grep --color=always 2013 | grep foo
```

would color `ID`, `2013` and `foo`.

```
grep --color=always ID file | grep 2013 | grep foo
```

would color `ID` and `foo`, but not `2013`.

**<sup>1</sup>Important:** You also have to remember that the added *clutter* from colors is passed
to next command in the chain. Once ID is colored, you can't (with ease), match e.g. `ID=111`.

---

On some occasion one would perhaps want terminal colors *in file*. Try e.g.

```
 grep --color=always foo file > result
 cat result
```

Though the resulting file would have very limited portability.

---

The coloring itself is also an extension.

---

As mentioned by the good [@slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm), you could add:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always"
```

to your `.bashrc` etc, **but don't** unless you for some reason really understand the implications and still want to do it. It would in many ways break `grep` due to the fact mentioned above <sup>1</sup>.

Add an `alias` if you use it often.

```
 alias cgrep='grep --color=always'
```

`GREP_OPTIONS` and `--color` [take three options](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep): `never`, `auto` and `always`. The two first should be the only ones considered for `GREP_OPTIONS`.

You could also check out `GREP_COLORS` in the `man` pages or at [gnu grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html).

Comment: Additional details on this methods pros/cons here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867877/preserve-ls-colouring-after-greping

Comment: add this to the answer too: `export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always"` in a .bashrc makes the options the defaults for any greps, and you've pretty much nailed it!

Comment: Good stuff in this Super Uuser Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/36022/less-and-grep-getting-colored-results-when-using-a-pipe-from-grep-to-less

Comment: "grep detects if output is to a pipe" -- aha! This is the key, grep isn't coloring if it's part of a pipe. There should be a substitution principle against this sort of thing :-/

Comment: @Chris2048: This is standard for most tools printing colors to terminal. You might find some more detail [by this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63108/number-of-lines-outputted-by-ls/63110#63110), on how it is detected, [And this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72799/pass-colors-from-ls-through-pipe-to-awk-print-statement/72804#72804) show some issues by e.g. ls and colors on OSX native `ls` and gnu coreutils.

Comment: export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always" is deprecated (2019), and 'alias cgrep='grep --color=always''' isn't available inside bash functions.

Comment: How do I make grep preserve colors from piped input and NOT add color to the match (i.e. only use grep to filter lines)?