# No colored output in less for the ls command

Tags: osx, pipe, ls, colors, less

If I run `ls` I get colored output which I find pretty handy for quickly getting a glance of the kind of file. When I try to pipe it to `less` even with the `-r` and `-R` flags the coloring always get lost. I am using `zsh` version 5.0.7. Any ideas? Thanks.

edit: I am on OS X.

Comment: Can you confirm `ls` is being invoked with `--color`? Try suspending the pipeline (`^Z`) or using `ps` from another terminal. What output does `which ls` produce?

Comment: I cleared this from the close queue since the OP has clearly stated that they're using `less -r` so it is not an issue with `less` but with `ls`

Comment: I'm surprised that this isn't a duplicate yet, but the closest I could find was [Store command output in variable](http://superuser.com/q/843403/150988), and that's on Super User.

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure if there is exact duplicate, but there some questions for which answer is very similar (`ls` result depends on stdout). The one I remember is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157285/why-does-ls-wc-l-show-the-correct-number-of-files-in-current-directory which itself is marked as duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/output-from-ls-has-newlines-but-displays-on-a-single-line-why

Comment: @jimmij But those questions don't mention that `ls --color=auto` means use color only when writing to a terminal (i.e., when the standard output is a terminal), and not when it's a file or a pipe.

Comment: @terdon `which ls` outputs `ls: aliased to ls -G`

Comment: @nunos not sure why you're addressing me, I didn't ask you that :) Anyway, since we now know you're using OSX, the answer is to set `CLICOLOR_FORCE` as explained in Gilles' answer.

Comment: @terdon: my bad, I meant zackse, thanks though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is by design: programs that produce colored output typically do so only when their output goes to a terminal, not when it's sent to a pipe or to a regular file. The reason is that data sent on a terminal is presumably read by a human, whereas data piped to a program or written to a file is likely to be parsed by some program, so it shouldn't contain extraneous content like color-changing escape sequences.

GNU `ls` displays colored output on a terminal when you pass the option `--color` (or `--color=auto`). To force colored output regardless of the file type of the standard output, pass `--color=always` or `--color=yes` (they're synonyms). This convention has been followed by other commands, like GNU grep, FreeBSD grep, `git diff`, etc.

```
ls --colors=yes -l | less
```

With the FreeBSD version of `ls` (also found on OSX, and available as the `colorls` port on OpenBSD and NetBSD), pass the option `-G` to display colors when the output is a terminal. Set the environment `CLICOLOR_FORCE` to display colors regardless of the output file type.

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -l | less
```

Comment: For some other commands on OSX (e.g. `eslint`), you have to use `--colors` and pipe to `less -r`.

Answer (score 26):

The problem most probably is that your `ls` program has set option `--color=auto` which basically means that output should be coloured only if it is connected to terminal, otherwise (output connected to a pipe or a file) no colors are emitted.

If you want to have colors is such cases you should set `--color` option to `always`, so try

```
ls --color=always | less -R
```

If this behaviour is what you expect all the time then just create alias:

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
```

Comment: In my setup, bash version 4.3, --color is an illegal option.. Grepping for "color" tells me about the "-G" option but doesn't say anything about an auto or always option. Any ideas?

Comment: @nunos `ls` doesn't come from `bash`, it is standalone program. Run `ls --version` to check its version. Mine is ls *GNU coreutils) 8.21*.

Comment: @jimiij my `ls` version doesn't have the `--version` flag. I am using the default one from OS X, not sure if that helps.

Comment: @nunos please _always_ mention your operating system. There are huge differences between Linux and non-GNU nixes like OSX.

Answer (score 0):

*I can't comment @jimmij 's answer, because I have less than 50 rep, but I would like to explain what worked for me in Bash.*

If you run

```
$ man ls | grep color
```

you will see all the entries of the `man`-page for your specific shell environment (in our case `bash`).

For me the following adjustment did the trick:

```
$ alias ls='ls -G'
```

Comment: That worked for what? The `-G` flag has nothing to do with how `ls` manages its colored output. That just removes the groups from the output of `ls -l`. It does affect color output in BSD ls (the one used on OSX as well), is that what you mean? In any case, I don't think that will show color when redirected to a file, it will just show color on the command line.