# Why doesn't `less` show bold output?

Tags: colors, less, fdisk

I'm connected to a bash shell on my ubuntu 16.04 server using Putty on Windows.

This is what it looks like in Putty when I do `sudo fdisk -l`:

[image: fdisk with bolding]

But when I try to pipe the output into `less`, the colors are not shown:

[image: fdisk piped into less]

I have tried `sudo fdisk -l | less -R` and `sudo fdisk -l | less -r`, but the output never looks the same as the raw output.

How can I get the output from `less` to look the same?

Comment: The problem was getting `fdisk` to output colors when piped more than getting `less` to retain colored output.

Comment: @localhost the answer is the same, so it's actually a duplicate

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc nowhere in that question do I see `fdisk` mentioned. The arguments are the same, but someone reading that question could not know that `fdisk` happens to have the same color argument as `git diff`.

Answer (score 11):

The culprit is not `less`, but `fdisk`: Many programs only color their output when they print to a terminal, and don't color it when the output is redirected, because in general you want to avoid breaking scripts with the ESC-codes used for colors.

However, usually these programs also have switches to manually turn on coloring. So try

```
sudo fdisk --color=always -l | less
```

instead, and look it up in the man-page for other commands.

Comment: Actually, try `... | less -R`.

Comment: not only fdisk but most other programs don't output color when piping, try `ls` or `grep`

Comment: [No colored output in less for the `ls` command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185544/44425), [`less` and `grep`: Getting colored results when using a pipe from grep to less](http://superuser.com/q/36022/241386)

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Make that an answer?