# How to know if output is being redirected to a file?

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, ls, stdout

I am working on displaying output like `ls` command (just ls, no options). And I have a working program using the system calls. But I experienced a strange behavior while testing as shown below.

```
$ ls 
a b c
$ ls > somefile
$ cat somefile
a
b
c
```

so, as you see the output is written one file per file, NO ADDITIONAL SWITCHES WERE GIVEN TO LS. You can test it out. So from above I infer, `ls` command has some built-in logic to display it one per line if written to a file via redirection.

To add to the puzzle, I believe it's the shell that interprets the redirection.

So I am confused I would like to kown what exactly is making the output one per line if redirected to a file? Any hint?

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157285/why-does-ls-wc-l-show-the-correct-number-of-files-in-current-directory

Comment: In both `ls` invocations, the output is redirected to a _file_. In the first case, a device file, in the second case, presumably a regular file, in anycase not a terminal device file, as otherwise you'd see `a b c` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Usually by testing if a relevant filehandle is attached to a tty:

```
% perl -le 'print -t STDOUT ? "yes" : "no"'
yes
% perl -le 'print -t STDOUT ? "yes" : "no"' > out
% < out
no
%
```

Or via C, something like:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

int foo;
if (ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, FIONREAD, &foo) == -1) {
    printf("yes\n");
} else {
    printf("no\n");
}
```

Comment: Specifically, it uses the `isatty` C library call, which calls the `fstat` system call.

Comment: Or just `[ -t 1 ]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Please elaborate about `[ -t 1 ]`.