# How do I check whether my shell is running in a terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I want to perform some action only if my shell is "connected" to a terminal, i.e. only if my standard input comes from a terminal's input and my standard output (and standard error? maybe that doesn't matter) gets printed/echoed to a terminal.

How can I do that, without relying on GNU/Linux specifics (like `/proc/self`) directly?

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22162/117549

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[`isatty` is a function for checking this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html), and the [`-t` flag of the `test` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) makes that accessible from a shell script:

> **-t**  *file_descriptor*
>
> True if file descriptor number *file_descriptor* is open and is associated with a terminal. False if *file_descriptor* is not a valid file descriptor number, or if file descriptor number *file_descriptor* is not open, or if it is open but is not associated with a terminal.

You can check if FD 0 (standard input) is a TTY with:

```
test -t 0
```

You can do the same for FDs 1 and 2 to check the output and error streams, or all of them:

```
test -t 0 -a -t 1 -a -t 2
```

The command returns 0 (succeeds) if the descriptors are hooked up to a terminal, and is false otherwise.

`test` is also available as the `[` command for a "bracket test":

```
 if [ -t 0 ] ; then ...
```

is an idiomatic way to write this conditional.

Answer (score 14):

Just an extra note on top of the fine answers that have already been given. Note that `[ -t 0 ]` tests that the file descriptor 0 is open one a file that is a device file with a tty line discipline (typically, that's done by checking that a harmless termio(s) ioctl() succeeds).

Also, that doesn't necessarily mean there's a terminal or terminal emulator (with a real user typing on a keyboard) on the other end (though in the immense majority of cases and probably most of the ones you care about, that's good enough an approximation).

tty and pty devices can also be used for data transfer or as an interprocess communication mechanism.

For instance, one could do:

```
(stty raw -echo; myscript) < /dev/ttyS0
```

To feed what's received over RS232 to `myscript`.

```
echo test | ssh -tt host myscript
```

would have `myscript`'s stdin being a pty device (with `sshd` at the other end, and eventually (across the ssh connection) not a terminal, but a pipe fed by `echo`)

To further check that there is a terminal at the other end of that RS232 line or pty, you could also check that a `$TERM` variable is set and non-empty (`[ -n "$TERM" ]`) and send a *Device Status Report* escape sequence over that fd and check that you receive a response (in addition to the `[ -t 0 ]` and `[ -n "$TERM" ]`).

```
printf >&0 '\e[5n'
```

Is replied with a `\e[0n` by most terminals.

Now there are several problems with that, so I wouldn't recommend doing that except in the case where you want to check that because you want to run a visual TUI application (in which case, you'd be better off using libraries like `ncurses`, and instead of the DSR, you'd rather want to send a device identification escape sequence to query the type of terminal more precisely than via `$TERM`):

- Thankfully, in most cases where stdin is not a terminal, it will have been open in read-only mode which would cause that `printf` to fail, but in case stdin is a tty device open in read+write mode, that will have the side effect of sending that sequence to the other end. For instance in our ssh example above, that will actually send the sequence to a terminal (but the reply will not be coming on stdin)
- It's hard to read the reply reliably and portably. You'd need to change the tty line discipline temporarily and read one byte at a time. You'll also need to decide a timeout by which if the reply is not seen, you give up and decide there's no terminal. If you want to consider people dialing in over satellite connections, that means a long timeout.
- Reading from a terminal when in background would suspend your script with a SIGTTIN signal.